# Chart Displaying Odd Axis Labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have created a chart that counts and display occurrences of a range of dates.  The axis labels for each column display the date like this:

"Thursday March 17, 2016, Friday March 18, 2016"

The next column is labeled "Friday, March 18, 2016, Saturday, March 19, 2016"

And so on.  I tried to add a label field, using just the days of the week, and that ended up labeling it thusly:

"Thursday, Friday"
"Friday, Saturday"
"Saturday, Sunday"

I(and probably no one in the world) need it to display the information this way.   Especially because the first date it shows is actually the wrong date, and the second date is the actual date being counted.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a Histogram.  I changed to a Bar Chart and the problem disappeared.  Leaving this here in case anyone ends up with this problem!

Comment: In a histogram, each entry is a range and shows the number of data points in that range. So 'Monday, Tuesday' is to be understood as a range.